# how to check the number of connections open towards internet from a linux server?

Tags: linux-networking

We have issue where the response time from a endpoint is specifically having more response time for one server but not on other server. Further we found that this issue happens for all endpoint which are in internet like "curl 'ww.google.com'". More analysis lead us to know that this happens only during a particular time. So to know i want to know how list the HTTP connection made by host to internet. please  help me on this.

Comment: How about `tcpdump` with filters?

Comment: `ss -tan | grep :80`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list number of active connections made from local linux machine to remote machines on port 80 on remote machine you can use netstat to list active connections, and get the specific port from Foreign Address column:

```
netstat -tnap | awk '{print$5}' | grep :80 | wc -l
```

netstat -tnap will give you all active connections, and you can then list only the ones made on port 80 on foreign address using awk, by listing only the fifth column, and greping connections on port 80 on foreign address will give you all remote addresses, you can then get number of connection with piping to wc -l.

you can also use ss - socket statistics, suggested by MadHatter, as netstat is getting deprecated and replaced by ss

```
ss -tan | awk '{print$5}' | grep :80 | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides netstat or ss, as others suggested, I find `lsof` (list open files) to be useful.With `-i` option, it lists network files or sockets, as everything is a file in UNIX. With `-i4`, you can narrow that down to IPv4 followed by `:80` or `:443` to specify the port number for `http` or `https` respectively. Check the man pages for ls to get more details.

```
 
[root@kauai tmp]# lsof -i4:80 -n
COMMAND     PID   USER   FD   TYPE    DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
firefox    4128 daniel   76u  IPv4 111733311      0t0  TCP 192.168.10.103:50500->198.252.206.149:http (ESTABLISHED)
firefox    4128 daniel   96u  IPv4 112109229      0t0  TCP 192.168.10.103:51201->198.252.206.149:http (ESTABLISHED)
firefox    4128 daniel  108u  IPv4 111452598      0t0  TCP 192.168.10.103:50410->198.252.206.149:http (ESTABLISHED)
clock-app 31704 daniel   21u  IPv4 126088871      0t0  TCP 192.168.10.103:55146->23.67.61.171:http (ESTABLISHED)

[root@kauai tmp]# lsof -i4:443 -n
COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE    DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
firefox 4128 daniel   52u  IPv4 125964214      0t0  TCP 192.168.10.103:45435->23.67.118.140:https (ESTABLISHED)
```